# ubuntu samba gio mount issue: volume doesn't implement mount

Tags: ubuntu, samba, gvfs

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04 where I also installed xubuntu-desktop.

In thunar I can access my samba share by typing smb:/// in the address bar. After which it prompts me for my credentials. Everything is accessible.
Issue 1: I cannot find the mount in /run/user/<my_uid>/gvfs nor ~/.gvfs, so that I could also access the files in the terminal.

Issue 2: If I run `gio mount smb://<servername>/<folder>` I get the error:

```
gio: smb://<servername>/<folder>: volume doesn’t implement mount
```

Issue 2 is both the case when (a) I run this in an ssh terminal (b) a terminal window in the desktop environment. I have tried various proposed solutions using dbus-launch with no results.

I have no idea what is going on. Is 20.04 using a different system than gio?

Note: I cannot use cifs mount as it requires sudo privileges (which I cannot give to the users that need to use it). I cannot use an fstab entry as every user needs to login using their own credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to start a dbus session first: `dbus-run-session bash`
See the more detailed solution [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1050076).